# Excel 2010 Move data from multiple columns/rows to single row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

So frustrating! I get data sent to me and it looks like this:

```
a  1
a     2  2
a           3  3
b  1
b     2  2
b           3  3
b                 4  4
b                       5  5
b                             6  6
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
a  1  2  2  3  3
b  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6
```

I have about 30 columns that need to move to the top value in their group, then removing the duplicates (to which there are about 33 rows of duplicates, trying to get it down to about 8 rows). I have been searching forums for several days and trying bits and pieces of code. I am having such a tough time with VBA!!!!

Same illustration, but graphically:

[image]
     →     [image]

Comment: 30 columns? Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems like a manual operation that'll take no more than 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your title says "Move data from multiple columns to a single row". But the example you provide (a1a22a33...->a12233...) looks like sorting a row (and possibly eliminating duplicates). Can you be more specific about exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it to make it more visually correct. I just need to move all the values in the columns 'up' to the first value that starts the duplicates in the primary column.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly; you are trying to remove the `---` so you can remove duplicates and sort the data?

Comment: Is the identifier (a or b in the examples) always a single character? Is there any consistency to the offsets between rows of data, for instance you've got a space after the b on the line with two 3s?

Comment: Good question. I am not allowed to post images yet so the '----' are supposed to be blank columns. So, this might be confusing, each character is supposed to signify a different column. Letter "A and B" column A/row1, Number 1 = Column B/row1, first '2' = column C/row2, second '2' = Column D/row2, first '3' = Column E/row 3, second '3' = Column F/row 3, first '4' = Column G/row 4, etc to the last '6' = column L/row 6

Comment: Can you upload a picture to [hostr.co](https://hostr.co/) or similar and link it? Struggling to understand the problem.

Comment: Jason, the identifier is not a single character, they are names

Comment: http://hostr.co/CBfMGH4BdNDF

Comment: Do the names (represented by a and b in your example) have a fixed width? Do additional rows always only include new information after the length of the previous row, or could there be "a 1 - 3" followed by "a - 2" such that the output is supposed to be "a 1 2 3". Is the supplied data in order, like the example?

Comment: No, they do not have a fixed width.

Comment: Excellll,I will try the below answer. If it works, do you think I can record a MACRO to accomplish the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this without VBA in a few seconds. Just follow these steps.

**WARNING: This process will overwrite your original data. If you want to keep the original data, do not do this.**

1. Select your data, as far to the right as you need to select everything.

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>F5</kbd>. Click `Special...` in the Go To dialog that pops up. Select `Blanks` and click `OK`. This will select all the blank cells in your data.

   [image]
3. Without clicking anywhere, paste the following into the formula bar. Be sure to adjust the cell references to match your data.

   > =IF($A2=$A1,C2,"")

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will apply the formula to all the selected cells. The formula checks if the row below has the same value in column A. If so, it returns the value immediately below. If not, it returns nothing.

   [image]
4. Now, select all your data again, copy it and `Paste Special...` > `Values` back into the same range. This will remove the formulas you just entered but will keep the values.
5. Finally, with all your data selected, go to the Data ribbon and select `Remove Duplicates`. Remove duplicates based on column A (the column with values a and b).

   [image]

   This will keep the top row for each value in column A and remove the rest. You should be left with what you want.

   [image]

Comment: I will try the below answer. If it works, do you think I can record a MACRO to accomplish the steps?

Comment: A recorded macro won't be general enough for this to work in all cases you could run into. For example, the formula used depends on where the first blank cell is, which will likely be different for different data. You'll have to go into the VBA editor and figure out how to make it general. If your goal is to have a reusable VBA procedure, personally, I'd skip recording the macro and just write my own code that doesn't follow this exact procedure.

Comment: The above worked so Thank you very very much. I would like to have a VBA reusable procedure, so maybe I will record a MACRO and reverse engineer it.