# How can I group row values sum them and turn them into column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table where I have various costs that have been grouped can captured by row.

In the rows structure in the first row is the value I want to remain as a row, the second column has the transformed column name and the third row the value to sum.

This is a little like this question [Excel: How to extract group of the same rows and their values into columns?](https://superuser.com/questions/799667/excel-how-to-extract-group-of-the-same-rows-and-their-values-into-columns) but I want to include sums and power query would provide a suitable answer.

***Prior to transform***

| Location | Expense Type | Description | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City 1 | Food | Burger | 100 |
| City 1 | Food | Sausages | 50 |
| City 1 | Transport | Hover bike | 1000 |
| City 2 | Entertainment | Cinema | 320 |
| City 2 | Food | Brocoli | 15 |
| City 2 | Transport | Bus | 22 |
| City 2 | Transport | Train | 8 |

***After Transform***

| Location | Food | Transport | Entertainment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City 1 | 150 | 1000 | 0 |
| City 2 | 15 | 30 | 320 |

Looking for the optimum way to do this, ideally it would handle additional entries without having to adjust the formula this will drive a subsequent vlookup.

Comment: What problem did you run into when you tried the Table.Pivot method in Power query (or even a simple Pivot Table in Excel)? Either would provide the results you show in your question.

Comment: When I tried to use the pivot function it ended up with a whole heap of nulls,  I'm probably missing some small detail, hence im looking for an example

Comment: According to your sample, the general pivot table is helpful. **Locations** is Row field, **Expense Type** is Column field and **Value** is Values field.

Comment: If you used Power Query, please edit your post to show the code you used (copy/paste from the Advanced Editor), so we can tell what you are doing incorrectly. It seems pretty straightforward from your data.

Comment: @Emily I don't want to use a pivot table, the out put needs to be an independent table.   And not copy pasting aftewards

Comment: @RonRosenfeld i worked out the problem, in the real example there were a number of extra columns. They were messing with the pivot so I removed those columns from the query and it worked.  I'll update the question and then answer it for future ref

Comment: Glad to hear that. Now you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using power query

**Power Query Code**

```
 let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Location", type text}, {"Expense Type", type text}, {"Description", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Description"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[#"Expense Type"]), "Expense Type", "Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

**Step by step instructions**

1. Select the Range
2. Select "Data from the menu"
3. Select "From Table / Range"

[image: Screenshot selecting the range]

4. Remove the description column

[image: Screenshot removing the description column]

5. Select the column "Expense Type" then select pivot
6. On pivot chose "Value" as the value column and sum in the aggregation

[image: Pivot settings]

7. The column would have pivoted, so now click close and load (under file)

[image: Final Step]

[image]